# Addslashes safe to protect against xss in array?

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, xss

Came across some code today that had a javascript array, made in php, using only php's addslashes() to sanitize. At first **I thought this was an easy XSS vulnerability, but I haven't been able to see it's flaw**. Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

foo.php

```
$itemList = "[";

foreach ($array as $item) 
{
    $itemList .= "'".addslashes($item)."',";
}

$itemList = "'']";
```

bar.html

```
<script>
    var a = <?php echo $itemList; ?>
</script>
```

Obviously something like `']; alert("xss"); b=['` won't be effective because it will be turned into `\']; alert(\"xss\"); b=[\'`. **So is this really safe, and my code smell is non-existent?**

`

`

**Edit:**

Can someone show me *how* this doesn't work? I know that this is not best practice, and would not use this in my code, but if I want to rewrite the code I need **proof** to convince others

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, no no no no **no**.

Use the right function for the right job.

`addslashes` is **not** an escape function for any context, it just adds slashes.

If you're printing to HTML use `htmlentities` (or `htmlspecialchars` if applicable).

If you're printing to JavaScript use `json_encode`.

If you're building a MySQL query use `mysql_real_escape_string`

etc.

---

Oppurtunities for abuse when using `addslashes` instead of `json_encode` is for instance the string:  `"</script><iframe src=hxxp://phising.mywebsite.com>"`

This will end the script and insert an iframe from an untrustworthy and potentially harmful domain.

Comment: I understand that it is not the right tool. This is in a pre-existing code base I saw. What I'm curious about is, is this vulnerable in the real world? I know what the best practice is

Comment: Yes, it is vulnerable. addslashes is not unicode aware, and there's a fair number of valid unicode characters that addslashes will happily turn into injection chars.

Comment: At the very least you can get a syntax error which will break the whole page.

Comment: Wouldn't unicode just be broken when the backslash in \u0027 is escaped to \\u0027?

Comment: I hope the poster isn't implementing this because just tested it in a small piece of code and it does breaks the page. And its just the start!

Comment: Can you give me an example? I really want to prove this as broken, but can't send this up the line without proof

Comment: One really simple example is the string `"</script>"`, this will end the script and spill the rest of it into plain view. Then you can add stuff like `"<iframe src=hxxp://phishing.mywebsite.com>"`. `json_encode` escapes the `/` for exactly (and only) this reason.